# Notepad++ Remove \s in between brackets

Tags: notepad++, whitespace, brackets

Im trying to get a RegEx to work which will remove all blank spaces in between angle brackets of a text. But I can't get past this specific problem:

First off, this is the RegEx I am working on

```
([<].*\s[>])
```

The brackets enclose a tag which will be read by another program, thus there cannot be spaces. Here's an Example

`<tagname>foreign text with space that needs to stay like this</endtag>`

sometimes though, they will look faulty (tags with spaces in between):

```
<ta gname>foreign text with space that needs to stay like this< /endtag>
```

My expression fails because it will include everything from the first < to the last >. I was thinking about how to approach this problem and i think it could be done if I delete all \s that border a latin text character (the tags are the only latin characters in the texts).
So I thought something like:

```
([<>]\s\?[A-Za-z]\s\?[<>])
```

And replace it with

```
\1^\s
```

But apparently it isn't that easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following regex based search and replace:

```php
(?:\G(?!^)|<)[^>\s]*\K\s++(?=[^>]*>)
(?:\G(?!^)|<)[^<>\s]*\K\s++(?=[^<>]*>)
```

and replace with an empty string. See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/CuZZdg/1).

***BONUS similar patterns*** for different kinds of brackets:

- **Round brackets / parentheses**: `(?:\G(?!^)|\()[^()\s]*\K\s++(?=[^()]*\))` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CuZZdg/4))
- **Square brackets**: `(?:\G(?!^)|\[)[^][\s]*\K\s++(?=[^][]*])` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CuZZdg/3))
- **Custom different delimiters**, say, `|'` and `'|`: `(?:\G(?!^)|\|')(?:(?!\|'|'\|).)*?\K\s++(?=(?:(?!\|'|'\|).)*'\|)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CuZZdg/2))

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|<)` - either the end position of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or the `<` symbol
- `[^>\s]*` - 0+ chars other than `>` and whitespace
- `\K` - omits all text matched so far
- `\s++` - 1+ whitespaces (matched possessively for better performance)
- `(?=[^>]*>)` - a check that requires 0+ chars other than `>`followed with `>` right after 1+ whitespaces.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works splendidly. The RegEx also identifies that after a `<` there can be no discontinued string until a `>`occurs.

The last operator really helped a lot! I would like to try it on this:
`([<][^>]*>[</?][^>]*>)` to check if every bracket is closed to make sure there are no doubles like <tag> <tag> or </tag> </tag>

Comment: `([<][^>]*>[</?][^>]*>)` worked other than expected. It matches these strings: `<tag<` and `>/tag>`. It does not match `>tag>` and `</tag<`

Comment: Sorry, that sounds like another question. Please feel free to ask. However, bear in mind that checking nested tags is not the best task for a regex.

Comment: You are certainly right. I will look into that another time. Is there something you would recommend for checking tags effectively?

Comment: I have not had any need to do that so far, so, Google recommends https://validator.w3.org/ and other online checkers.

Comment: I see - I stumbled apon these as well. Note to readers: validator.w3.org does not yet support txt-type files.